# Python BeautifulSoup Error Testing

Tags: python, testing, indexing, beautifulsoup

I need to test if a web element contains a certain portion of text.  If so, I want it to print out the text.  If not, I want it to print an error message.  The following code works only for items that contain the text, not for the ones that do not.:

```
if a[3].find_all('img')[1]:
    print a[3].find_all('img')[1]
else:
    print "Does not exist."
```

How can I correctly test whether this object exists?

Comment: I think you just want `if a[3].find_all('img'):`, i.e. did `find_all` find anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the `IndexError` exception that is thrown if there is no item at index 1:

```
try:
    print a[3].find_all('img')[0]
except IndexError:
    print "does not exist."
```

Alternatively,  test if there are at least two elements (e.g. the item at index 1 exists):

```
images = a[3].find_all('img')
if len(images) > 1:
    print images[1]
else:
    print "does not exist."
```